# Display duplicate lines in two different files

Tags: linux, bash

I have two files and I would like to display the duplicate line. I tried this but it doesn't work :

`cat id1.txt | while read id; do grep "$id" id2.txt; done`

I am wondering if there are any other way to display the duplicate lines in the file.
Both of my 2 files contain list of ids.
Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate by ID or by the whole line? Adding some example data would help.

Comment: either way works. if you know both ways would be nice. thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Are the files sorted?  Can they be sorted?

If sorted:

```
comm -12 id1.txt id2.txt
```

If not sorted but using `bash` 4.x:

```
comm -12 <(sort id1.txt) <(sort id2.txt)
```

There are solutions using temporary files if you don't have `bash` 4.x and ['process substitution'](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).

You could also use `grep -F`:

```
grep -F -f id1.txt id2.txt
```

This looks for the words in `id1.txt` that appear in `id2.txt`.  The only problem here is ensuring that an ID `1` doesn't match every ID containing a `1` somewhere.  The `-w` or `-x` options available in some versions of [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control) will work here.

Answer (score 14):

If by detecting duplicates you mean printing lines which are the present in both files (or duplicate within one file), you can use `uniq`:

```
$ cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -d
```

Comment: Why not: `sort file1 file2 | uniq -d`?

Answer (score 3):

use awk will save your time.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{lines[$0]=1;next} $0 in lines' id1.txt id2.txt

#explaination
FNR==NR #check whether the File NR equal to NR, 
#which will only be true for the first file
lines[$0]=1 #put the contents into a dictionary, 
#value is 1, key is the lines of the first file
next #do not do the next commands if FNR==NR
$0 in lines #check whether the line in the second file
# is in the dictionary
#if yes, will print the $0
#acturally, I omitted the {print},
#which is default to print by awk if condition is true
```

Comment: This is very clever. Can you please explain the logic too. Thanks.

Comment: Works must better then 'comm' version because do not require sorting of file's content and output is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `comm` command instead:

```
sort id1.txt > id1.txt.sorted
sort id2.txt > id2.txt.sorted
comm -12 id1.txt.sorted id2.txt.sorted
```

If you want to do it in one command:

```
comm -12 <(sort id1.txt) <(sort id2.txt)
```

Arguments to `comm`:

- The `-1` argument suppresses lines unique in the first file.
- The `-2` argument suppresses lines unique in the second file.
- If you pass a `-3` argument, it would suppress the common lines.